# Client side validation for a form loaded in bootstrap modal via ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, validation, unobtrusive-validation

In my ASP.Net Core application I need to use both validation (server site and client sid) in bootstrap modal form, I succeed to perform a server side validation but I fail with client side javascript validation.

I followed and tried everything mentioned in the following links with no luck:

- [Manually register the form with the unobtrusive validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23890017/1890313)
- [Include my modal form to DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625857/1890313)
- [Unobtrusive Client Side Validation in ASP.NET Core](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/asp-net-core/asp-net-core-unobtrusive-client-side-validation/)

I also add the required javascript files in the correct order:

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/site.js"></script>
```

I shared my sample project in [Github-Repository](https://github.com/AYElsharif/AjaxModalValidation.git), the project has no error and the server side validation works fine.

How can I correctly perform the client side validation?

Answer (score 0):

I tested with your codes on github,the source of your script was not correct,I modified to

```
<script src="~/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
......
```

It works well on local right now:

[image]

Comment: I changed the source of script but still get the server side validation, I put a break point in controller post method and when I hit save I go to this method.